# New install preserving home directory

Tags: 12.04, installation, 64-bit, lvm

I have 32bit 11.10 installed on an LVM disk taking up all 500 GB, and I would like to install 64bit 12.04 on top, preserving the data in my home directory.

I used to do that pre-LVM by just not formatting the partition mounted as `/home`, installing over `/` and `/usr` and formatting `/tmp`, But now it don't recognize the partition table.

I've never had much luck with `upgrade` and so I just install afresh when I want a new version.

Surely I can do what I want, can't I?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a new install with formatting all partitions except home partition.

Comment: Can you provide more detail? Right now, this doesn't seem to say anything different from what the OP tried said he tried to do, in the question.